# Remove horizontal cell borders in SlickGrid?

Tags: css, slickgrid

I'm trying to remove the horizontal cell borders in SlickGrid.  I'm trying this:

```
var columns = [
    {id="col0", name:"Column 0", field:"imgUrl", cssClass:"cell-image"},
    {id="col1", name:"Column 1", field:"col1", cssClass:"cell-text"},
    {id="col2", name:"Column 2", field:"col2", cssClass:"cell-text"}
];
```

And in my CSS:

```
.cell-text {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-top: none;
}
```

A side effect of this is that my `cell-text` cells are 1px higher than my `cell-image` cell, causing the grid to look jagged.  **Is there a way to remove borders from cells?**  I'd be willing to create a formatter that does this as well, if that's the best way to go.

Comment: Why .cell-text or .cell-image?  If you're trying to remove horizontal lines from all cells, shouldn't you set that in .slick-cell?

Comment: The issue is that I have multiple slick grids.  If I edit slick-cell, it will affect the other grids, which I don't necessarily want.  Is there a way to override the .slick-cell for only the grid that I want?

Comment: Just your good old basic CSS.  Set a marker class on one of the container sand specify a descendent rule: ".no-lines-grid .slick-cell { ... }".

Comment: @Tin, that worked, wana write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a marker class on one of the containers and specify a descendent rule: "`.no-lines-grid .slick-cell { ... }`".